# Angular unit testing - test ng-content

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an expansion panel component that wraps content dynamically:

```
<div class="expansion-panel">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

If you'd use this component it would be like this

```
<expansion-panel>
  // any content
</expansion-panel>
```

I want to write a unit test that checks whether the content renders correctly, but I can't find any way to insert some content (other than `fixture.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'content'`, but that's not the right way). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [test host component](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host) for your test:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <expansion-panel>
      content
    </expansion-panel>
  `,
})
class TestComponent {
  @ViewChild(ExpansionPanelComponent, { static: false }) child: ExpansionPanelComponent;
}

describe('ExpansionPanelComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent, ExpansionPanelComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should render content', () => {
    expect(component.child.innerText).ToEqual('content');
  });
});
```

As above, you can use `component.child` to access the `<expansion-panel>` instance

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. `.innerText` and `.innerHTML` are always `undefined`.

Comment: I got it working by checking `fixture.nativeElement.innerText`. I'm not sure it's the 'right' way, but it gets the job done :)